# values object is not updated while using react-select inside field array

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-select, react-hook-form

Since I want my variation form to be dynamic, I have used the concept of field array from `react-hook-form`. For the select field I am using `react-select` which is used for taking multiple values for a particular option from the user. This is how I have done

```
import React from "react";
import { useForm, useFieldArray } from "react-hook-form";

import ReactSelect from "./Select";
import Input from "./Input";
import VariationPreview from "./VariationPreview";

const initialValues = {
  variations: [
    {
      id: 1,
      option: "Size",
      values: [
        { id: 1, label: "SM", value: "sm" },
        { id: 2, label: "MD", value: "md" }
      ]
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      option: "Color",
      values: [
        { id: 1, label: "Red", value: "red" },
        { id: 2, label: "Blue", value: "blue" }
      ]
    }
  ]
};

const VariationSetup = () => {
  const {
    register,
    control,
    handleSubmit,
    formState: { errors },
    watch,
    getValues
  } = useForm({
    defaultValues: initialValues ?? {}
  });
  const { fields, append, remove } = useFieldArray({
    control, // control props comes from useForm (optional: if you are using FormContext)
    name: "variations" // unique name for your Field Array
  });
  const variants = watch("variations");
  console.log("variants", variants);
  return (
    <>
      <p className="font-semibold mb-4 text-md">Options</p>
      {fields.map((field, index) => {
        return (
          <React.Fragment key={field.id}>
            <div className="flex mb-4" key={field.id}>
              <div className="w-full md:w-4/12">
                <Input
                  name={`variations.${index}.option`}
                  label="Option"
                  placeholder="Choose option"
                  options={VARIATION_OPTION}
                  helperText="Choose option that can be applied as variants for a product"
                  errors={errors}
                  register={register}
                />
              </div>
              <div className="w-full md:ml-4 md:w-8/12">
                <ReactSelect
                  name={`variations.${index}.values`}
                  label=""
                  placeholder="Choose value"
                  options={[]}
                  helperText="You can choose multiple values"
                  wrapperClassName="mt-7"
                  errors={errors}
                  register={register}
                  isCreateable
                />
              </div>
            </div>
          </React.Fragment>
        );
      })}
      <button
        className="bg-gray-200 p-3"
        type="button"
        onClick={() => append({ option: "", value: "" })}
      >
        Add option
      </button>
      <div className="divide-y"></div>
      {/* PREVIEW */}
      <VariationPreview variations={watch("variations")} />
    </>
  );
};

export default VariationSetup;

const VARIATION_OPTION = [
  { id: 1, label: "Size", value: "size" },
  { id: 2, label: "Color", value: "color" }
];
```

this is the react-select with hook-form binding

```
import { Controller, useForm } from "react-hook-form";
import Select from "react-select";
import CreatableSelect from "react-select/creatable";

export default function ReactSelect({
  disabled,
  label,
  helperText,
  name,
  placeholder,
  options,
  defaultValue,
  className,
  labelClassName,
  wrapperClassName,
  isCreateable = false
}) {

  const {
    control,
    formState: { errors }
  } = useForm();

  const getDefaultValue = (value) => {
    if (value && value.length) {
      return value[0];
    } else return value;
  };

  return (
    <div className={wrapperClassName ? wrapperClassName : ""}>
      {/* TODO: Label as a separate component */}
      <label
        htmlFor={name}
        className={
          labelClassName
            ? labelClassName
            : "block font-semibold mb-2 text-gray-700 text-sm tracking-wide uppercase"
        }
      >
        {label}
      </label>
      <div className="mt-1 relative">
        <Controller
          name={name}
          defaultValue={getDefaultValue(defaultValue)}
          control={control}
          render={({ field }) => {
            const styles = errors[name] ? errorStyles : customStyles;
            if (isCreateable) {
              return (
                <CreatableSelect
                  isMulti
                  {...field}
                  isDisabled={disabled}
                  placeholder={placeholder}
                  options={options}
                  styles={styles}
                  className={className}
                />
              );
            } else {
              return (
                <Select
                  {...field}
                  isDisabled={disabled}
                  placeholder={placeholder}
                  options={options}
                  styles={styles}
                  className={className}
                />
              );
            }
          }}
        />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Here the problem is when I update values field the variations object does not get updated because of which I cannot update Variation Preview table. Also when if I add new option, the option key gets updated and is reflected in VariationPreview table but when I add values for that option the values object is shown empty. Could anyone point me where i did the mistake? I have a code in playground either

https://codesandbox.io/s/elegant-robinson-fiujlj?file=/src/Variation.jsx:0-2764

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You call `useForm` inside the `ReactSelect` component. Now there are two unrelated forms. That's why variations object does not get updated.

You can pass the `control` down to `ReactSelect` and use it for `Controller` component.

And for errors handling:

```
const { errors } = useFormState({
  control
});
```

Comment: It worked but it duplicates previous data again while changing the options.

Comment: may be this is unrelated.

Comment: @Serenity There is a bug with the duplicated keys. It's a different problem. You can use something like this: ```obj["id"] = `${product.join("-")}-${i}`;``` https://codesandbox.io/s/intelligent-margulis-0mfds7?file=/src/VariationPreview.jsx Please, update the original question with more details.

Comment: It's working fine. Thank you very much for your help. I appreciate your time and help.